# .NET Core with jquery.validate.unobtrusive: error messages are missing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, razor, unobtrusive-validation

I am using `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` with .NET Core to do client-side validation. I see the form validation is working (upon error the input is turning red ...) but I do not see the error messages. I think error messages should be visible, at least that's I have seen sofar [link1](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) [link2](https://wakeupandcode.com/validation-in-asp-net-core/)

[image]

I have already done:

1. import scripts for `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`
2. `ClientValidationEnabled = true`
3. Added `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` validation attributes

I cannot post the whole code so [this the repository](https://github.com/amir734jj/side-project-exhibit/tree/69f5280f5d806d8b0be9596ef670c6878a40a99a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the following in razer:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ValidationSummary on top like below:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
<!-- your fields here -->
```